# Fade in a long list of item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I would like to fadeIn a list of item, one after one, with jQuery.

My HTML:

```
<div>
 <span>h</span>
 <span>e</span>
 <span>l</span>
 <span>l</span>
 <span>o</span>
 <span></span>
 <span>w</span>
 <span>o</span>
 <span>r</span>
 <span>l</span>
 <span>d</span>
 <span></span>
 <span>m</span>
 <span>y</span>
 <span></span>
 <span>n</span>
 <span>a</span>
 <span>m</span>
 <span>e</span>
 <span></span>
 <span>i</span>
 <span>s</span> 
</div>
```

I can write my JS like this but it would not be really optimized:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('span').hide();

    $(window).load(function() {
        ('div span:nth-child(1)').fadeIn( function() {
             ('div span:nth-child(2)').fadeIn( function() {
                 ('div span:nth-child(3)').fadeIn( function() {
                    // etc... 
                });
            });
        });

    });

});
```

How can write something like "when a span has faded in, fade in the next one"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than targeting each `span` using `nth-child()`, use `.each()` to loop through each `span`.  The following will delay each `fadeIn()` to happen one after another. Just change the delay value to modify the speed:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1a6mwb13/1/)

```
$('div span').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(100 * i).queue(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().dequeue();
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, it seems to be the shortest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two recursive solutions:

```
function fadeIn(i) {
    $('div span:nth-child('+ i +')').fadeIn( function() {
        fadeIn(i+1);
    });
}
```

Just start with `fadeIn(0)`.

And the other one working without an explicit index:

```
function fadeIn(elem) {
    $(elem).fadeIn(function() {
        fadeIn(elem.next());
    });
}
```

Now start with `fadeIn($('div span').first())`

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to wrap your code in `window.load` since you are already using jQuery document ready.

If you want to hide all the span on page load use a CSS for that and once the DOM is ready, iterate through your span and do the fadein.

Give your div an id (#parent) and use this CSS to hide all the span inside that

```
#parent > span {

    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#parent").children("span").each(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```